# How to use multiple versions of unison on one system?

Tags: version, unison

I have two machines. One with unison v. 2.40 (Debian Jessie) and a new one (Debian Stretch) where I installed package `unison-all`, which brought in unison versions 2.32, 2.40 and 2.48. However, I was unable to make my 2.40 work against the new machine, since it only presented v. 2.48. No matter what I do, I get:

```
expected "Unison 2.40\n" but received "Unison 2.48\n\000\000\000\000\017",
```

I worked around the issue by removing `unison-all` and installing v. 2.40 explicitly, but I wonder what to do if I ever want to use two concurrent versions of unison on this machine.

Comment: I have the same issue, but can not fix it the way you mentioned. If I install the package unison-all on Stretch it only installs 2.48. See [https://lists.debian.org/debian-user/2017/12/msg00425.html] "Since stretch only has 2.40 (corrected the typo) in its repo, it can only pull that one in."

I also tried to install unison 2.48 on Debian Jessie [http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=10&t=134431], but this overwrites unison 2.40 which I still need for syncs with other servers.

How did you manage to get unison 2.32, 2.40 and 2.48 on Debian Stretch? This is what I need!

Comment: I'm looking at my deployment but it looks as described above. I have package `unison-all`, it depends on `unison`, `unison2.40.102` and `unison2.32.52`.
`apt-cache policy unison-all` tells me that my version is `2.48+2` and that I'm using `stretch/main amd64 Packages`.
I'm sorry but I cannot confirm that Stretch only has unison 2.48. I still see all three versions on offer.

Comment: Too late to help most people, but I can report that, for the **Wheezy** to **Jessie** upgrade, the **Jessie** version of Unison was **2.40.102-2** and the **Wheezy** version was **2.40.65-2**. As such, the standard `unison` package sufficed for syncs done between a **Jessie** client and a **Wheezy** server.

Comment: Again, too late to help most people, but I also report that, when I had the **Stretch** version of **unison** loaded on the client and the **Jessie** version of **unison** loaded on the server, I was able to replace said **Jessie** version with the **Stretch** version (from the standard **Debian Stretch LTS** repo). Even though said server was rocking **Jessie**, this scheme worked just fine...YMMV, of course...

Comment: Once again, too late to help most people, but I can report that, as far as **unison** compatibility goes, the _dist-upgrade_ from **Debian Stretch** to **Debian Buster** was painless, similar to my experience in going from **Wheezy** to **Jessie** (see the pertinent comment, above).

Comment: @Digger There are [static releases](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/771980/198901) for Unison, which are much easier than juggling with Deb packages on different servers. Unison is a cool project, I'm happy to have found a solution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I just ran into this problem myself, and it took quite a bit of searching to find the answer! So here it is, and it works for me.

To use multiple versions of unison, install `unison-all`. Then...

**Using multiple versions of Unison on the *client***

Choose a specific version to run by appending the version number, like so:

```
unison-2.40 ...
```

Or, if you want to run the latest version, you can simply type:

```
unison
```

**Using multiple versions of Unison on the *server***

Instruct the client version of Unison to invoke the matching version of Unison on the server using the `-addversionno` tag, like so:

```
unison -addversionno
```

**For futher details**

and if you still get an

```
Fatal error: Received unexpected header from the server
```

see this [solution](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/330870/unison-addversionno-received-unexpected-header-from-the-server).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for dropping a note. However, I think your setup is the opposite of mine. I have multiple versions of unison on the **remote** machine and a single one on my **local** machine where I run the command. So locally I have nothing to chose from. I tried, of course, but the behavior is the same as before.

Comment: Youre right, I have the opposite setup. In your case: I see that the unison man page lists an advanced option ` -addversionno` that  adds the version number to name of unison on server. Sounds like that might be what you need?

Comment: Yes! This (-addversionno) is the solution I was looking for. Thanks! I really could not find that. Are you going to expand your answer with that so that I can upvote and accept it?

Comment: Done! Glad that helped.

Comment: `unison-all` sadly doesn't help when there's only one available unison version per system, which seems to be the case for most systems.

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to install [static Unison releases](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/releases), than to hope that every client and server will have the exact same system version.

I deleted unison Debian package from every system, and launched the exact same script everywhere:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
set -e

mkdir /tmp/unison
cd /tmp/unison
curl -LO https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/releases/download/v2.53.4/unison-2.53.4-ubuntu-x86_64-static.tar.gz
tar xvfz unison-2.53*
cd bin
chmod 755 unison unison-fsmonitor
sudo chown root:root unison unison-fsmonitor
sudo mv unison unison-fsmonitor /usr/local/bin/
cd /tmp/
rm -r unison
unison -version
```

Every client and server can talk together now, because they agree on:

```
❯ unison -version
unison version 2.53.4 (ocaml 4.14.1)
```

No issue with libc, ocaml or holding packages anymore! And I can use a recent Unison version even on old servers.