# unison -addversionno Received unexpected header from the server

Tags: version, unison

Following instructions in [How to use multiple versions of unison on one system?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/233504/how-to-use-multiple-versions-of-unison-on-one-system) I have used

```
unison -addversionno
```

to sync a **Debian** and **Raspbian** system, but received this error

```
Contacting server...
Fatal error: Received unexpected header from the server:
 expected "Unison 2.48\n" but received "bash: unison-2.48: command not found\n", 
which differs at "b".
.
:
```

It seems like the same versions are found but misinterpreted as incompatible.

What can I do to get it working?

I have also filed a bug on [GitHub](https://github.com/bcpierce00/unison/issues/52).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As it turned out in the discussion regarding the bug report *-addversionno* currently truncates the version info at the minor number.

I had installed

```
unison-2.48.3
```

at the server and client (by copying the binary), but *-addversionno* was looking for

```
unison-2.48
```

which did not exist.

As a workaround I created the symbolic link unison-2.48 pointing to unison-2.48.3.

```
ln -s unison-2.48.3 unison-2.48
```

Now it works as expected.